# How to get ALL of the cookie info that you see in Chrome debugger using Java?

Tags: java, google-chrome, cookies, httpurlconnection

When I visit a certain web page with my F12 chrome browser console open, I see all the ajax sub-pages it calls to load the data for the main page under the Network tab.  In the Network->XHR->Headers->Request Headers->Cookie, I see a long semi-colon-separated list of name=value pairs.  I want to retrieve that same long cookie using java.  My attempts have only produced a subset of the data.

Here is my code

```
List<Property> scrapePropertyInfo(List<Date> auctionDates, String docName) {
    int idx1 = docName.indexOf(".");
    String county = docName.substring(8,idx1);
    int idx2 = docName.indexOf(".",idx1+1);
    String referer = docName.substring(idx1+1,idx2);

    long ms = getNewYorkTimeInMillis(county,referer);
    String urlStr = "https://" +county +"." +referer +".com/index.cfm?zaction=AUCTION&Zmethod=UPDATE&FNC=LOAD&AREA=W&PageDir=0&doR=1&tx=" +ms +"&bypassPage=1&test=1&_=" +ms;
    System.out.println("urlStr="+urlStr);
    String str = null;
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    for (Date date:auctionDates) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlStr);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
            con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01");
            con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.9");
            con.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
            con.setRequestProperty("Host", county +"." +referer +".com");
            con.setRequestProperty("Origin", "http://evil.com/");
            con.setRequestProperty("Pragma", "no-cache");
            con.setRequestProperty("Referer", "https://" +county +"." +referer +".com/index.cfm?zaction=AUCTION&Zmethod=PREVIEW&AUCTIONDATE=" +df.format(date));
            con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36");
            con.setRequestProperty("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
            con.connect();

            //handle cookies
            List<String> cookies = con.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie");
            con.disconnect();
            con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();     //create new connection with cookies
            for (String cookie : cookies) {
                System.out.println(cookie.toString());  
            }       
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RealAuction.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RealAuction.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return properties;
```

This produces the following output:

```
AWSELB=E7779D5F1C1F6ABE3513A5C5B6B0C754520B66675A71020B72C56F9BA4662D2646DC6C44241A76E20A0CD248944F72B9267D1E1CAA354099C2BA89199637524B7708F46664;PATH=/
CF_CLIENT_BREVARD_REALFORECLOSE_HC=2;Path=/;Expires=Sun, 20-Oct-2019 19:02:45 GMT
CF_CLIENT_BREVARD_REALFORECLOSE_TC=1563822165128;Path=/;Expires=Sun, 20-Oct-2019 19:02:45 GMT
CF_CLIENT_BREVARD_REALFORECLOSE_LV=1563822165128;Path=/;Expires=Sun, 20-Oct-2019 19:02:45 GMT
cftoken=0;Path=/;Domain=.realforeclose.com;Expires=Wed, 21-Jul-2049 02:54:15 GMT;HTTPOnly
cfid=aafd3f03-8096-454f-8d21-f36dae5c0f2d;Path=/;Domain=.realforeclose.com;Expires=Wed, 21-Jul-2049 02:54:15 GMT;HTTPOnly
Url: https://brevard.realforeclose.com/index.cfm?zaction=AUCTION&Zmethod=UPDATE&FNC=LOAD&AREA=W&PageDir=0&doR=1&tx=1563829357220&bypassPage=1&test=1&_=1563829357220
```

But when I look at the cookie from the browser F12, I see there is more info that was not returned by Java:

```
cfid=a26e0967-8ff9-4458-958a-8a2987ba9c57; cftoken=0; AWSELB=E7779D5F1C1F6ABE3513A5C5B6B0C754520B66675A407900314ABAC5333A52E93FD1A8D7401D89BC8D5E8B98059C8AAC5507D12A2C6ED07F7E7CB77311BD7FB09B738DB945; _ga=GA1.2.1667505039.1563644762; _gcl_au=1.1.17070058.1563644762; __utma=162497519.1667505039.1563644762.1563644763.1563644763.1; __utmc=162497519; __utmz=162497519.1563644763.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); CF_CLIENT_BREVARD_REALFORECLOSE_TC=1563817824875; testcookiesenabled=enabled; _gid=GA1.2.1923687150.1563822309; _gat=1; CF_CLIENT_BREVARD_REALFORECLOSE_LV=1563822308548; CF_CLIENT_BREVARD_REALFORECLOSE_HC=152
```

This other info, such as _ga=GA1.2.1667505039.1563644762; _gcl_au=1.1.17070058.1563644762; __utma=162497519.1667505039.1563644762.1563644763.1563644763.1; __utmc=162497519; __utmz=162497519.1563644763.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none);
is not returned.  It is apparently needed because an empty value is returned without it.

Why is this code not returning all of the cookie properties shown in chrome?

Comment: Please somebody respond!

Comment: Since apparently no one has any ideas or suggestions, I'm forced to give up on this approach.  Moving to selenium to automate the cut and paste of each page.